# How to apply KNN algorithm to randomly generated two arrays

Tags: python

I was asked a question as "Generate 20 x and y values .(20 each) randomly. use rand function The numbers will be between 0-1. If there exists cluster find them Using the nearest neighbor algorithm k=5"

Yet, what I could not understand is that I need my independent variable to be an integer number like 0 or 1. Because we use Binary Classifier in KNN algorithm. So, how can I solve this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import random

dataSetX = random.rand(20)
dataSetY = random.rand(20)

print(dataSetX)
print(dataSetY)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataSetX,dataSetY,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

trainDataSet = pd.DataFrame({'X':X_train,'Y':y_train})
print(trainDataSet)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1)
classifier= KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the output of the KNN prediction to be an integer either 0 or 1?

Comment: The question was directly asked like this and while I was trying to code, I realized that the output must be integer instead of float values. Then I thought that scaling could be a solution yet in that case the question loses its point.

Comment: Did u try to use np.round() ?